# Hide/show menu Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a menu where you click the title to show the contents.
I want to make it exactly like the one in Google's Inspect element below:
[image]

I managed to write this code:

```
<script>
$("label").click(function () {
  $("p").slideToggle("fast");


if ($((this).html).find('&#9654;'));
{   
    document.getElementById("lbl_name").innerHTML = '&#9660;' + document.getElementById("lbl_name").innerHTML.substring(1);

}   

else if ($((this).html).find('&#9660;'));
{   
    document.getElementById("lbl_name").innerHTML = '&#9654;' + document.getElementById("lbl_name").innerHTML.substring(1);
} 


});
```

the &96... is the right and down arrows

But I've got problems with this code:
1- It doesn't work, after it changes the arrow for the first time it doesn't change it again.

2- I don't want the function to work with element ID, because I want it to work with many texts not just one, so I want it for example to work with the caller of the function instead of changing all paragraph tags.

the html:

```
    <label id="lbl_name">&#9654;Toggle</label>
  <p>
    This is the paragraph.
  </p>
```

Comment: What's your (relevant/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) HTML? Can you [show a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've got already?

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<label><span>&#9654;</span>Click Me</label>
<p class="p">this is a sample text..</p>
```

css:

```
         <style>
            .p {
              display: none; 
            }                
        </style>
```

javascript: // if you have jquery earlier than 1.9 , you can use `toggle`

```
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("label").toggle(function(){
                    $(this).find("span").html('&#9660;');
                    $(this).next("p").slideDown(500);
                },function(){                    
                    $(this).find("span").html('&#9654;');
                    $(this).next("p").slideUp(500);
                });
            });            
        </script>
```

Comment: thanks but I can't get it to work, i added the html, css, and js, but when I click the text the paragraph doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Ive made something similar... try to capture what to do inside the event. To dont use id, try using class intead or just the `.next()` jquery function like I did:

```
$('p > .arrow').on('click', function(e) {
  var $el = $(e.target);
  if($el.hasClass('arrow-right')) { // so this is hide! show it
    $el.next('p').slideDown('fast');
    $el.removeClass('arrow-right');
    $el.addClass('arrow-down');
  }
  else { // is visible, hide it
    $el.next('p').slideUp('fast');
    $el.addClass('arrow-right');
    $el.removeClass('arrow-down');
  }
});
```

You HTML must be something like:

```
<p>
  <span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod temp
  <p><span class="arrow arrow-right"></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consect</p>
</p>
```

Comment: Could u please give me an example, because i'm just a beginner and I don't know where to put those classes.

Comment: See above with the HTML sample